# Derive state space model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to derive the state space model for the following system

$$ L \ddot{\theta} - g \sin(\theta) - \ddot{z} \sin(\theta) = 0 $$

I am allowed to use that $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$. And I must set $x_1 = \theta$, $x_2 = \dot{\theta}$, input $u = \ddot{z}$, output $y = \theta$.

This is what I have come up with:

$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} &= \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{x}_1 \\
   \dot{x}_2
  \end{bmatrix} =
  Ax + Bu =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   \frac{g}{L} & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  x
  + \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   \frac{\theta}{L}
  \end{bmatrix} u\\
  y &= Cx + Du = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}x
\end{aligned}$$

But I can't have the $\theta$ in $B$, since that is equal to $x_1 = y = \theta$, right? How should I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is $g$? A constant?

Comment: Yes g is gravity!

Comment: As in $$g \approx 9.80665\ \mathrm m\ \mathrm s^{-2}\quad \large ? $$

Comment: Yes, exactly! But $g\approx 9.82 ms^{-2}$ in Sweden ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nonlinear model, even if you linearize $\sin\theta$ to $\theta$. If you want to linearize it further you would also have to assume that $\theta$ stays close to one value and use that value to define $B$. But if you want to solve this differential equation you could use [separation of variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationofVariables.html),

$$
\int\!\!\!\int \frac{1}{\sin\theta} d\theta\,d\theta = \int\!\!\!\int \frac{g + u(t)}{L}dt\,dt,
$$

but the left hand side does [not yield a nice solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsin(x)+dx+dx).